# HTML card CSS transition

Tags: html, css, transition

I created a card using HTML.The text class div only comes out when text class div is hovered.How can I change the HTML and CSS so that text div comes out when parent div is hovered.

```css
.bg {
  background-color: white;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  border: solid red 2px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.text {
  background-color: gray;
  position: relative;
  top: 180px;
  transition: top 0.5s;
}

.text:hover {
  top: 132px
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  <div class="text">
    <h3>Test text</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Reiciendis voluptas pariatur qui aut animi molestiae quia veritatis culpa excepturi. Nesciunt optio ipsa molest</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, just make the rule `.bg:hover .text { top: 132px }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add sibling div with text class div and add parent div for both divs and write transition for parent div as follows

```
<style>
        .bg{
            background-color: white;
            width: 200px;
            height: 300px;
            border: solid red 2px;
            overflow: hidden;

        }
        .text{
            background-color: gray;
            position: relative;
        }

        .inner{
            height: 200px;
        }
        .outer{
            position: relative;
            top: 2px;
            transition: top 0.5s;
        }
        .outer:hover{
            top: -65px;
        }
    </style>



<div class="bg">
        <div class="outer">
            <div class="inner"></div>
            <div class="text">
                <h3>Test text</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Reiciendis voluptas pariatur qui aut animi molestiae quia veritatis culpa excepturi. Nesciunt optio ipsa molest</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: @Saubhagya out of curiosity, why would you accept this answer which requires you to modify your DOM structure and add unnecessary HTML elements and CSS rules?

Answer (score 4):

Move the hover to the parent. E.g. `.bg:hover > .text`

```css
.bg {
  background-color: white;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  border: solid red 2px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.text {
  background-color: gray;
  position: relative;
  top: 180px;
  transition: top 0.5s;
}

.bg:hover > .text {
  top: 132px
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  <div class="text">
    <h3>Test text</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Reiciendis voluptas pariatur qui aut animi molestiae quia veritatis culpa excepturi. Nesciunt optio ipsa molest</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you have the selector set to `.text:hover`. This will default to applying the styles to the element being hovered, which is `.text`.

Instead, you can use `.bg:hover .text` to manipulate the `.text` element.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```css
.bg {
  background-color: white;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  border: solid red 2px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.text {
  background-color: gray;
  position: relative;
  top: 180px;
  transition: top 0.5s;
}

.bg:hover > .text {
  top: 132px
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  <div class="text">
    <h3>Test text</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Reiciendis voluptas pariatur qui aut animi molestiae quia veritatis culpa excepturi. Nesciunt optio ipsa molest</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I know you probably want to gain rep, but there is an exact answer posted previously to yours. Please make sure you are adding something different (that works) if there are already answers.

Comment: Whoops, looks like someone beat me to it :/
Anyway to delete my post?

Comment: Yeah, there is a delete link available for you below your post I believe. But, you might as well keep it here since you got the up vote. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just pass `.text` class after hover to activate like this `.bg:hover .text{}`

```css
.bg {
  background-color: white;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  border: solid red 2px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.text {
  background-color: gray;
  position: relative;
  top: 180px;
  transition: top 0.5s;
}

.bg:hover .text {
  top: 132px
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  <div class="text">
    <h3>Test text</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Reiciendis voluptas pariatur qui aut animi molestiae quia veritatis culpa excepturi. Nesciunt optio ipsa molest</p>
  </div>
</div>
```